# SuiteCRM : Change task status color on dashlet

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'am using 7.9.2 Suitecrm, i need to change task status color on dashlet, but can not find the html code of this. And need to know how to find path of any module.
I need custom change of task dashlate design.

Answer (score 0):

Using the developer tools in Chrome, target the element you want to change the color of, add the new CSS using the panel on the left-hand side, and then copy your CSS and paste it at the end of the `themes/{YOUR-THEME-FOLDER}/css/style.css` with a comment.

Repair and then rebuilt it.